# Scrolling to end of list with NetworkImageView Volley

Tags: android-listview, android-volley

I am creating a chat view and loading images in a chat room using NetworkImageView (placed inside a Normal ListView) via Android Volley Framework, which works great but the problem is that when the chat gets loaded the images are downloaded after a while due to which scrolling to the bottom does not work as expected. What I want is the listview in which the images are kept should scroll to the end upon getting initialized.

Here is the code that does the scrolling to the bottom of the list:

```
                listview.clearFocus();
                listview.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        listview.setSelection(listview.getCount() - 1);
                    }
                });
```

However, this does not scroll to the end of list. The issue is that volley does not load up the image by the time it is initialized and only initializes it when it is starting to get displayed (onAttachToWindow or onLayout calls). Refer to the [code](http://goo.gl/V38y0j)

A workaround to make sure the list gets scrolled is:

```
networkImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholderImage);
```

Although not a good solution, this gets the job done.

Anyone has better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `setStackFromBottom(true)` solves the issue. I don't know why it never came to my mind. Anyways, putting the question for people like me, having issues with volley.